# How to create a statistics descriptive table

Tags: tables

I will be grateful if you can help in creating a table like this? Especially, how to create break in the line?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "how to create break in the line". The screenshot you posted does not appear to feature any in-cell line breaks.

Comment: Any news? Does any of the answers meet your expectations? If so, be so kind and accept it by clicking on check mark at top left side of selected answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tabularx` for table, `siunitx` for `S` column type and `makcell` for writing column header texts in two column, where is neccessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{iwona}  % sans serif 
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[!h]
    \sisetup{group-four-digits}
    \renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
    \small
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}
                    L 
                    S[table-format=4.0]
               *{4}{S[table-format=9.2]}
                            @{} }
        \toprule
Variables 
    & {\makecell[b]{No de\\ observaciones}}
        & {\makecell[b]{Media}}
            & {\makecell[b]{Desviacion\\ Estandar}}
                & {\makecell[b]{Minimum}}
                    & {\makecell[b]{Maximum}}         \\ 
    \midrule
Credito Hipotecario   
    & 3 275 & 30 745 206.66  & 12 148 247.72 &  12 032 977.6 &  51 196 863.91
        \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
Depositos en el systema financiero  
    & 3 275 & 189 825 138.7  & 58 845 344.85 &  99 131 392   & 296 185 499.5 
        \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
Numbero de noticias de crimen
    & 1 050 &  18 636        &     76 038    &           0   &         503   
        \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
Tasa de referencia BCRP   
    &   132 &                &     11 077    &       5 088   &          26.38          
        \\  \addlinespace[2pt]
more items
    &       &                &               &               &
        \\  \bottomrule %
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I rewrote only first four table rows, other I left to you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet your requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\begin{document}  

\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\scriptsize #1}}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\scriptsize}p{4.5cm}}
\newcolumntype{R}{*{5}{>{\scriptsize}c}}

\begin{table}[!h]

\begin{tabular}{@{}P@{\kern-30pt}R@{}}\toprule 

\texttt{variables 1} 
& \mc{No of observations}              
&\mc{Media}
&\mc{Standard Deviation}
&\mc{Maximum}&\mc{Minimum}\\[-2pt]
\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr) 
{6-6}
introductory payments   & 3,275 & 1,23,45,678.23  & 1,23,45,678.23 & 
1,23,45,678.23 & 1,23,45,678.23\\ 
current personnel cost  &3,275  & 12,34,56,789.99 &12,34,56,789.99 &12,34,56,789.99 & 
12,34,56,789.99  \\ 
current cost for\newline &1,050 &13.572         &13.572        &13.572 &13.572\\[-8pt]
system maintenance      &&&&&\\
\bottomrule %
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```